# Java Swing TextArea unexpected attitude

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextarea

When I call this method inside class, works. When I call it outside of the class, TextArea doesn't change. While string values are correct.

```
public void printMessage(String prefix, String message) {
         System.out.println(prefix + message); // works
         textArea1.setText(textArea1.getText() + prefix + " " + message + "\n"); // works only if called from this class
    }
```

Comment: how you call textArea1 from another class? is textarea1 a class field? is it private or public?

Comment: I call this method from outside the class. It's class field. It's private, but does it really matter if method is public? EDIT: changing to public didn't solve the problem.

Comment: no, it is not. On what object you call this method? could you add more code? Maybe it doesn't work because you use it on different instance of class which contain this method

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: `textArea1.setText(textArea1.getText() + ..` See `textArea1.append(..`

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself. There was no problem with this code. I didn't initialize instance of this class properly.